# Modify a function to call/step through a table

Tags: mysql, stored-functions

I was provided with a function in a question earlier this month that returns a bearing given two longitude and two latitude points:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `initial_bearing`$$

CREATE FUNCTION `initial_bearing`(
    lat1 DOUBLE, lon1 DOUBLE, 
    lat2 DOUBLE, lon2 DOUBLE
 ) RETURNS DOUBLE
NO SQL
DETERMINISTIC
COMMENT 'Returns the initial bearing, in degrees, to follow the great circle route
         from point (lat1,lon1), to point (lat2,lon2)'
BEGIN

RETURN (360.0 + 
  DEGREES(ATAN2(
   SIN(RADIANS(lon2-lon1))*COS(RADIANS(lat2)),
   COS(RADIANS(lat1))*SIN(RADIANS(lat2))-SIN(RADIANS(lat1))*COS(RADIANS(lat2))*
        COS(RADIANS(lon2-lon1))
  ))
 ) % 360.0;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

How could I modify this so it would step through a given table, and use MinLatitude, MaxLatitude, MinLongitude, MaxLongitude from each record in place of the variables in the function and then return the output, bearing, to the Bearing field in the same record?

Answer (score 0):

I mistook the way stored procedures work vs stored functions my bad.  In fact this procedure works nicely and simply needs to be called as part of a query e.g. Select initial_bearing (Lat1, Long1, Lat2, Long2) from TableA. I figured I'd leave this up in case any other beginner makes the same mistake. Sorry for the waste of bandwidth.